# Current Working directory for WCF Application

Tags: wcf, web-services, com

I have an VB6 com object which i need to wrap it in .net and expose as WCF web service.

The com .dll has some configuration files which needs to be placed in it current directory.

For testing the com object, i have created a console application and executed, from the logs generated by the component i can see that it is pointing to current directory and getting the config files and working as expected.

Now when i host this in WCF service, Com object stoped working. I wondered and gave below command in my wcf application

```
    Logger.Log("current path: " + System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

Now in my log i see that current path is "c:\winnt\system32" !!!!!! And concluded that this might be the reason why the component is not working as expected in wcf.

Note: I have published my wcf into another folder in "d:" drive.

My Question :

What is the reason behind "c:\winnt\system32"?

Thanks for your help!

[Update]

Now it gets wierd, I have changed current directory with below method.

```
    System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()
```

Now the dll points to below path

C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\service\b5fc8f06\28f29236\assembly\dl3\1945abc0\00563626_8b5bce01\

Comment: If you use `SetCurrentDirectory("C:\")`, does that change the directory to "C:\"? Then use an absolute path in the `SetCurrentDirectory` call.

Comment: Yes the path gets changed.. but the com dll got copied to "00563626_8b5bce01" folder while executing webservice.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to install the COM object, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: May be, i need to check with vendor on that